# Django no me renderiza formulario

Tags: python, django, djangorestframework, python-requests

Estaba haciendo un TP para entregar y necesito hacer un formulario para pedir informacion de mi base de datos, dicha informacion es metida tambien por distintos formularios; pero al iniciar el programa y entrar en la seccion buscar, el programa me toma directamente desde " no agregaste nada ", se saltea el bucle if y entra en el else,lo que da como resultado que no me deje ni siquiera buscar algo; se resuelve el else.

```
from .models import Materia, Evaluacion, Profesor
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.db import models
from cursos.models import Profesor


def buscar_informacion(request): 
   
    return render(request, "buscar.html")
    

def buscar(request):

    if request.POST:
        producto=request.POST["info"]
        articulos=Profesor.objects.filter(nombre_icontains=Profesor)

        
        return render(request, "resultado_busqueda.hotml",{"articulos": articulos, "query":producto })



    else:
        mensaje="no has introducido nada"


    return HttpResponse(mensaje)
```

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Esto te está ocurriendo porque al cargar la vista "def buscar(request)" la primera petición que realiza Django para renderizar es una de tipo GET, por tanto, si tu condición es "if request.POST:" siempre que cargues la vista esta condición será siempre "false" esto provoca que te envie directamente al else
---> mensaje="no has introducido nada"

Recomendaciones:

1. Cambia la validación del if por algo como esto:

   if request.method == 'POST':
2. Utiliza dentro de la validación if un "try" "except" para manejar los errores del request que realices.
3. Si necesitar renderizar el html primero, implementa una opción de vista por defecto si la petición no es de tipo "POST", es decir dile a django que tiene que renderizar si la petición no es de tipo "POST"

saludos, espero te sea de ayuda.